# With inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt$ on $L_2[0,2\pi]$ how do $||f||$, $||f||_2$ and $\langle f,f\rangle$ relate?

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

So this is more an issue of understanding syntax. It is given just about anywhere $||f||^{2}=\langle f,f\rangle$ implying $||f||=\sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle}$, but what norm is $||f||$ representing? Which of the following is true:
$$||f||^{2}_{2}=\langle f,f\rangle \space \,\text{ or }\, \space ||f||^{2}_{1}=\langle f,f\rangle .$$
Without knowing which of the above (or both) are true, I am unable to have any confidence in computing $||f||_{2}^{2}$.

I hope my confusion makes sense, and I appreciate any help provided.

Comment: Use `\langle f, f \rangle` to get the correct MathJax syntax for $\langle f,f \rangle$

Comment: Note that $||f||_1=\int_0^{2\pi} |f(x)|dx$, which you can get as $\langle f, \operatorname{sign}(f)\rangle$, where the sign(x)=1 if x>0, -1 if x<-, and 0 if x=0.  So it can be defined in terms of the inner product, but it isn't the norm that you use when doing, e.g., fourier series.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, $\|f\|_1$ is not the norm of $L_2[0,2\pi]$ by definition; $\|f\|_2$ is. Secondly, $\|f\|_1$ does not satisfy the Parallelogram law (see the section “Parallelogram law” and “Real and complex parts of inner products” of [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)), so it cannot define a inner product. Thus, for your question, the norm is definitely $\|f\|_2$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!